# ASP.NET Formview dropdown with reference to other table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a SQL database with 2 tables, "Ingredients" and "Ingredient Types".
In my Ingredients table I have a foreign key linked to my Ingredient Types PK.

That works fine, when I try to fill in an incorrect value in the FK field I receive an error.

But... I want to replace the textbox on my edit form to an dropdownlist, the list must show the values from the Ingredient Types table.... (Code as PK, Description the value to show in my dropdown)

In my ASP.NET project I have made 2 SQL DataSources (SqlDataSource1 -> Ingredients table and SqlDataSource2 -> Ingredient Types table)

I created a Formview and linked it to SqlDataSource1 (The Ingredients table)
I replaced the textbox for a dropdownlist and linked it to SqlDataSource2:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="unitDropDown" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataValueField="Code" DataTextField="Description" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Code") %>' />
```

when I start my page I receive an error: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name Code.

But as far as I can see, I do have a column name Code

I added a picture with a screenshot from my SSMS with the 2 tables.. [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS8NP.jpg)

What do I do wrong? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: what happens when you either hard code the SelectedValue or remove it altogether? Are you getting the correct values in the dropdown?

Comment: Yeah when I remove it totally I get my values! Now I encounter another error but thats for tomorrow... Get some sleep now, Thanks for the help @DaniDev

Comment: With your other answer the puzzle is complete :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error is because you there is no column called "Code" in your SqlDataSource1 (BM_Ingridients) which is the table you are binding to.

You should try changing to:

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("IngridientType") %>'
```

which is the `ForeignKey` refrencing the corresponding value in your SqlDatasource2 (BM_IngridientsType).

Comment: To make it complete, this is the correct one: <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataValueField="Code" DataTextField="Description" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("IngredientType") %>'  />

Comment: Yes, "IngredientType" (foreignKey) is the correct field. I corrected my answer to reflect that. 
BTW, I upvoted your question because you did an excellent job of describing the issue and provided all the necessary information for me to be able to provide answer.